# UITableViewCell Selectioncolor hides everything

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

When I select a custom made cell it hides everything in the cell and shows only the selection color.

[image]

how can I just darken the background a bit when selected?

Comment: try to post some code...

Comment: the cell is done in IB. I am subclassing UITableViewCell. I have only getters and setters in that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively to overriding `setHighlighted:`, you can use the view makeup of a table view cell to your advantage.

When iOS applies the highlight, it is actually using the `selectedBackgroundView` property of each table view cell. So, you can make a custom UIView (style it however, such as giving it your desired background colour) and set that as the `selectedBackgroundView` property (`cell.selectedBackgroundView`) of the table view cell. Do this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, when customising the other details of your cell.

This will mean you take control of the selection yourself; the iOS default gradient will not be applied.

---

It is also possible to change the `selectedBackgroundView` via Interface Builder. In the same nib as your custom cell, create another view in the nib - not a subview of the custom table view cell - and wire that up with the `selectedBackgroundView' outlet of the custom table view cell.

Comment: I found the problem. The CustomCell's view was linked to backgroundView. Since I removed that link it works perfectly with your suggested selectedBackgroundView. Only problem is I can't set the cell's background anymore with cell.backgroundColor

Comment: Linked in the IB like you link an iboutlet to a lable

Comment: If you want to set your background colour now, you have to change the background colour of either the cell.backgroundView or cell.selectedBackgroundView themselves, as they now appear above the general cell's background colour.

Answer (score 2):

If that's a custom cell, implement

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
```

And adjust the background color within it.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add highlighted text color when you select cell.

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"part2.png"]];


cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Set selected Text Color as per your highlighted cell selection color.